# OrderBy is sorting differently in Chrome than other browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, sorting

I noticed that orderBy in Chrome is not sorting the same as it is in other browsers.

I am writing for a project in Angular 1.3.

Chrome sorting:
[image: Chrome]

IE 10 sorting:
[image]

There is no special logic regarding specific browsers and both arrays are EXACTLY the same.

The predicate is explicitly defined:

```
$scope.predicate = 'style';
$scope.reverse = true;
```

My ng-repeat looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="line in model.resultList | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
```

There's nothing special or different with my code. The 'sizes', however, are strings (e.g. size: '8-', ..., size: '6',...). Why is this sorting entirely differently on Chrome than on every other browser?

All of my results are coming in sorted from the back end in groups of style # and then ascending sizes. When the primary sort is set on Angular, in this case Style, Chrome is mixing up the already sorted sizes. Please see Plnk below (open in Chrome and IE/FireFox to see the difference)

http://plnkr.co/edit/6TO8pZZ8jZ8Tytw6wHpQ?p=preview

Comment: What is style properties? Can you provide fiddle with demonstration? It's not clear what is sorted property.

Comment: That's because chrome "is fast" therefore doesn't care about sorting, instead it does some shuffling just so you'd know that id didn't ignore your command completely.

Comment: Can't repro in this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ptx9SSTbOKCA3kTj58Af?p=preview)

Comment: you don't have to - it is a well known fact that Chrome (webkit) doesn't really support sorting and that Fx (geckos) are almost there, but not quite. The only browser that really supports sorting is MSIE.

Comment: @Andrey Please see updated question with additional info / Plunkr

Comment: @AlexChance Please see updated question with additional info / Plunkr

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see a property within your data called 'style', if you change the predicate to 'size', it will sort them correctly by your 'size' property.

Comment: @JordanMcRae, you'll need to read more about the "stable sort in javascript", and check the specifications of angular on what are the options and how is it done internally in order to be able to give some additional sorting instructions. - Relying on browser keeping order of collection is frail and completely unreliable.

Comment: @JordanMcRae I still don't get why you sorting by `style`, but there is no such field in your collection. Shouldn't predicate be `size`? - It will give consistent results

Comment: @AlexChance My mistake. That was a typo. I was simplifying the table from my codebase and forgot to switch that out. Please see updated plnk (it should default to 'material').

Comment: @Andrey My mistake. That was a typo. I was simplifying the table from my codebase and forgot to switch that out. Please see updated plnk (it should default to 'material').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing wrong. Since you're sorting by other field - size could be shuffled in any manner. `orderBy` relies on buit-in sort function of browser ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js#L219)). Browser implementations could be different. And sort shouldn't be stable ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [ES2015 Standard section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort)).

If you want to achieve consistent behavior use sorting by multiple fields. Like

```
orderBy:[predicate, 'size']:reverse
```

Comment: As an adition, and following your explanation, `sort()` will produce unexpected results even in the same browser.

Comment: @Andrey Thank you very much for all of your help!